# Redirect loop of death in Symfony2 security

Tags: php, symfony

I have an admin area with login that we are forcing to https://.  Hitting the route /admin should redirect to the login page if the user isn't logged in, but I'm getting an endless redirect loop. Not sure what's wrong, here's security.yml:

```
firewalls: 
        admin_login:
            pattern:  ^/admin/secured/login$
            security: false

        admin_secured_area:
            pattern: ^/admin
            provider: entity_admin
            form_login:
                check_path: /admin/secured/login_check
                login_path: /admin/secured/login
                default_target_path: /admin
            logout:
                path:   /admin/secured/logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/secured/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you try removing admin_login? from your firewall section?

Comment: Hi according to the docs I need admin_login to allow anonymous users access to the login form.  I tried removing as well and it still redirects.  Thanks though!

Comment: Please tell between which pages redirect going?

Comment: No need for a "admin_login" section in firewalls. Do you add ROLE_ADMIN role to logged users ?

Comment: Hi the redirect occurs when logging in from login to login_check.  I do have a ROLE_ADMIN, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi so this is related to the way that Symfony2 `$request->isSecure()` checks for SSL when the site is under a load balancer, there are some inconsistent header names in PHP.  The config file needs the following:

```
trusted_proxies: [10.0.0.0/8]
```

It now works, but I don't know if there are security issues with this setting though.

Comment: As a side note to this, you need to ensure that you're forwarding the correct header from the proxy. Symfony checks to see whether `X_FORWARDED_PROTO` = 'https', 'on', 'ssl', or '1'. You can see this variable by var_dump $_SERVER in app.php or app_dev.php

Comment: Hi Decave, can you elaborate on your comment?  What code do we need to ensure the correct header from the proxy?  Thank you!

Comment: You need to configure your proxy so that if it receives a request over https from the browser, that it forwards a `$_SERVER` variable that indicates that it received the request over https.

Are you familiar with how proxies work? If a proxy receives a request over https, it will sometimes forward that request to the web server over http. The web server therefore has no way of knowing whether the originating request was https, so the proxy has to forward a `$_SERVER` variable as reference instead. The `$_SERVER` variable that Symfony checks is `X_FORWARDED_PROTO`. Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm on AWS Elastic Load Balancers, it seems to be working, but this helps if I have any problems.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

No need for a "admin_login" section in firewalls. But it looks like you forgot anonymous parameter..

```
firewalls:     
        admin_secured_area:
            anonymous: ~
            pattern: ^/admin
            provider: entity_admin
            form_login:
                check_path: /admin/secured/login_check
                login_path: /admin/secured/login
                default_target_path: /admin
            logout:
                path:   /admin/secured/logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/secured/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }
```

As I said in my comment, do you set ROLE_ADMIN role for logged users ?

EDIT: Does your routing state HTTPS channel too for admin section ?

Comment: Hi thanks again for your help.  There's no need to set https in the routing, as we set it in the access_control.

Comment: I had a similar problem and, for me, worked adding `anonymous: ~` to `admin_secured_area`.

Answer (score 4):

After quick look I would say that something like this below should be correct:

```
firewalls: 
    admin_secured_area:
        pattern:  ^/admin
        provider: entity_admin
        form_login:
            check_path: /admin/secured/login_check
            login_path: /admin/secured/login
            default_target_path: /admin
        logout:
            path:   /admin/secured/logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/secured/(login|login_check|logout)$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }
```

Anyway, if this not help, I recommend to check the redirects with built-in profiler (tabs with route matches and logs), to turn it on the redirects change `config_dev.yml` to:

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: true
```

Comment: My headers in the request had the HTTPS set to off even if actually doing https... issue was nginx config not symfony, intercept_redirects: true ... helped me find it..

Answer (score 2):

`^/admin/secured/login_check` should by authenticated anonymously too as users won't have a role when they originally call that page, hence the loop.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion.  I tried this and it still fails.  Also there's no requirement for anonymous users on login_check in the docs, and the login works fine when not forcing https.  Thanks for the suggestion though.  I'll keeping working on this!

Answer (score 2):

Remove :

```
admin_login:
            pattern:  ^/admin/secured/login$
            security: false
```